# Function does not stay within wrapper

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I have a function that runs a query and pulls data from `MySql`database.  However when I run the query it does not stay within the `div` but if I do something like `$content2 = 'test'` it works.  Below is my `PhP` code and `CSS`

```
function runquery()
{
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'data');
$per_page = 6;
$query = mysqli_query($connect, 'SELECT cid, fname, lname,address, score  FROM customers');
while ($query_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo $query_row['fname'] . '<br />';
}
$content2 = runquery();
}
include 'templates.php';
```

And here is the Templates.php

```
<div id="content_area">
     <?php echo $content; ?>
     </div>
 <div id="content_area2">
     <?php echo $content2; ?>
 </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#content_area
{
float: left;
width: 750px;
margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
padding: 10px;
}
#content_area2
{
float: left;
width: 750px;
margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you observe? It may just be the CSS widths that are too large when floating. Have tried to tweak the CSS, or deactivate it to see what's happening?

Comment: Thats because `$content2 = runquery();` leads to an infinite loop my friend. The recursion never ends

Comment: I see that! Thank you Jay I think it's getting to late haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function needs to `return` not `echo` in your `while()` loop:

```
function runquery() {
        $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'data');
        $per_page = 6;
        $query = mysqli_query($connect, 'SELECT cid, fname, lname,address, score  FROM customers');
        while ($query_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
               $array[] = $query_row['fname'] . '<br />';
            }

        // Return
        return $array;
    }

// You assign the content outside the function.
$content2 = implode("",runquery());
```

Comment: Awesome! worked perfectly.  I can't believe I didn't see that.  Thank you again for the quick response!!

Comment: No problem! Sometimes the simplest things are the simplest to miss.